# How can I update inventory item quantity by calling NetSUITE REST API using postman

Tags: postman, netsuite, rest

I am using Postman to for using NETSUITE Rest API.

I have got the token using postman and using bearer token authentication.

I can see the item using the API call

```
{{REST_SERVICES}}/record/v1/inventoryItem/610
```

And the response I get is:

```
{
"links": [
    {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610"
    }
],
"assetAccount": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/account/125"
        }
    ],
    "id": "125",
    "refName": "1001 Stock"
},
"atpmethod": "CUMULATIVE_ATP_WITH_LOOK_AHEAD",
"autoLeadTime": false,
"autoPreferredStockLevel": false,
"autoReorderPoint": false,
"averageCost": 3.27,
"cogsAccount": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/account/126"
        }
    ],
    "id": "126",
    "refName": "5001 Cost of Goods Sold"
},
"copyDescription": false,
"cost": 2.61,
"costEstimateType": "LASTPURCHPRICE",
"costingMethod": "FIFO",
"costingMethodDisplay": "FIFO",
"countryOfManufacture": "GB",
"createdDate": "2014-10-17T16:34:00Z",
"currency": {
    "links": [],
    "id": "GBP",
    "refName": "GBP"
},
"custitem1": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem1"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem2": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem2"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem8": "B0041SO0C6",
"custitem_aptuss_1months": 135,
"custitem_aptuss_1weeks": 25,
"custitem_aptuss_3months": 357,
"custitem_hsnf_amz_asin": "B0041SO0C6",
"custitem_hsnf_amz_category": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_amz_category"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_amz_fba": false,
"custitem_hsnf_amz_flag": "Y",
"custitem_hsnf_amz_listinglink": "http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0041SO0C6",
"custitem_hsnf_amz_msrp": 5.75,
"custitem_hsnf_amz_node1": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_amz_node1"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_amz_node2": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_amz_node2"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_amz_node2filt_1": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_amz_node2filt_1"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_amz_node2filt_2": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_amz_node2filt_2"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_amz_nodefilt_1": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_amz_nodefilt_1"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_amz_nodefilt_2": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_amz_nodefilt_2"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_amz_price": 8.5,
"custitem_hsnf_amz_title": "Salon System Just Wax Vanilla Cream Wax with an Intoxicating Aroma of Vanilla 450g",
"custitem_hsnf_cosmos_naturalgoods": false,
"custitem_hsnf_cosmos_organicgoods": false,
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_account": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_ebay_account"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_bestoffer": false,
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_category": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customlist_hsnf_ebay_category_list/273"
        }
    ],
    "id": "273",
    "refName": "Shaving & Hair Removal -&gt;Waxing Supplies  : 82565"
},
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_category2": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customlist_hsnf_ebay_category_list/274"
        }
    ],
    "id": "274",
    "refName": "Shaving & Hair Removal -&gt;Other Hair Removal  : 11840"
},
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_condition": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customlist_hsnf_list_condition/1"
        }
    ],
    "id": "1",
    "refName": "New"
},
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_description": "Salon System Just Wax Vanilla Creme Wax is deliciously creamy with intoxicating aroma of vanilla.<p>  \r\n  \r\n<b>Key Features:</b><p>  \r\nTried and trusted by therapists, spas and salons.<p>  \r\nJust Wax is the leading range of professional depilatory products. <p>  \r\nAn excellent wax for removing unwanted hair from all areas of the body. <p>  \r\n  \r\nBrand leaders and experts in professional beauty, Salon System deliver an exclusive and comprehensive range of exceptional products for beauty therapists, nail technicians, salons and spas.<p>  \r\n  \r\nOur enduring philosophy is to develop products of exceptional quality that are easy to use with effective results. Lash enhancements, depilatory waxing, nail extensions, manicure, pedicure and skincare. <p>",
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_flag": "I",
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_gsp": false,
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_imm_paymt": true,
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_is_effect": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_ebay_is_effect"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_is_type": "Wax",
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_listinglink": "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/",
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_markdown_manager": false,
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_ratetable": false,
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_shipping": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customlist_hsnf_ebay_shipping_list/2"
        }
    ],
    "id": "2",
    "refName": "YODEL48/24/RM INT."
},
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_shop_category": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customrecord_hsnf_ebay_shop_cat/119"
        }
    ],
    "id": "119",
    "refName": "Waxing&gt; Wax : 4979908012"
},
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_template": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customlist_hsnf_list_ebaytemplates/5"
        }
    ],
    "id": "5",
    "refName": "Raddyx-mobile"
},
"custitem_hsnf_ebay_title": "Salon System Just Wax Vanilla Crème Cream Depilatory Hair Removal Waxing 450",
"custitem_hsnf_eligible_forsale_usa": false,
"custitem_hsnf_fba_de": false,
"custitem_hsnf_fba_es": false,
"custitem_hsnf_fba_fr": false,
"custitem_hsnf_fba_it": false,
"custitem_hsnf_image_url": "https://justbeauty-uk.s3.amazonaws.com/0202123_V2.jpg",
"custitem_hsnf_img_main_name": "0202123_V2",
"custitem_hsnf_inv_brand": "Salon System",
"custitem_hsnf_inv_cbm": 0.0,
"custitem_hsnf_is_crueltyfree": false,
"custitem_hsnf_is_vegan": false,
"custitem_hsnf_item_caseqty": "12",
"custitem_hsnf_item_discontinued": false,
"custitem_hsnf_item_hazardouscount": 0.0,
"custitem_hsnf_item_ishazardous": false,
"custitem_hsnf_item_isparent": false,
"custitem_hsnf_item_itemsize": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customlist_hsnf_list_itemsize/2"
        }
    ],
    "id": "2",
    "refName": "Packet"
},
"custitem_hsnf_item_organic": false,
"custitem_hsnf_magento_novariation": false,
"custitem_hsnf_mg_variation": false,
"custitem_hsnf_mtrx_prodcut_type": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_mtrx_prodcut_type"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_mtx_edition_variation": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_mtx_edition_variation"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_mtx_flavor_variation": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_mtx_flavor_variation"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_mtx_num_items": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_mtx_num_items"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_mtx_pillqty": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_mtx_pillqty"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_mtx_pilltype_variation": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_mtx_pilltype_variation"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_mtx_prod_variation": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_mtx_prod_variation"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_mtx_product_formulation": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_mtx_product_formulation"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_mtx_shade": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_mtx_shade"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_mygel_factory_kits": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_mygel_factory_kits"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_organic_food_fed": false,
"custitem_hsnf_s4y_category": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_s4y_category"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_tesco_uploaded": false,
"custitem_hsnf_valogix_itemclass_list": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customlist_hsnf_valogix_itemclass_list/14"
        }
    ],
    "id": "14",
    "refName": "UK Wholesale Replenishment"
},
"custitem_hsnf_vs_active": "Y",
"custitem_hsnf_vs_department1": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customlist_hsnf_vs_departments/16"
        }
    ],
    "id": "16",
    "refName": "Waxing : Wax"
},
"custitem_hsnf_vs_description": "<p>Salon System Just Wax Vanilla Creme Wax is deliciously creamy with intoxicating aroma of vanilla.</p>\r\n\r\n<p><b>Key Features:</b></p>\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n <li>Tried and trusted by therapists, spas and salons.</li>\r\n <li>Just Wax is the leading range of professional depilatory products.</li>\r\n <li>An excellent wax for removing unwanted hair from all areas of the body.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>",
"custitem_hsnf_vs_rrp": 7.65,
"custitem_hsnf_vs_sale_price": 7.65,
"custitem_hsnf_vs_tag_colour": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_hsnf_vs_tag_colour"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_hsnf_vs_title": "Salon System Just Wax Vanilla Wax 450gr",
"custitem_hsnf_vs_variation": true,
"custitem_lm_lastpurchaseprice": 3.27,
"custitem_nbs_brandlist": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customlist_nbs_brand/142"
        }
    ],
    "id": "142",
    "refName": "Salon System"
},
"custitem_nbs_excludedstorefrontreason": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_nbs_excludedstorefrontreason"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_nbs_excludedstorefronts": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_nbs_excludedstorefronts"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_nbs_excludedsubstorefronts": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/custitem_nbs_excludedsubstorefronts"
        }
    ]
},
"custitem_nbs_leightondennyflag": "F",
"custitem_nbs_multilanguageartworkcreat": false,
"custitem_nbs_requiresexpirydate": false,
"custitem_nbs_requiresmsds": false,
"custitem_nsts_rm_item_classification": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customrecord_nsts_rm_generic_class/1"
        }
    ],
    "id": "1",
    "refName": "All"
},
"custitem_omp_autoprint_bincount": false,
"custitem_omp_autoprint_receipt": false,
"custitem_preload_stockcount": 52.0,
"custitem_sps_item_synch": false,
"custitemlastpostedtofarapp": "2020-04-07 20:48:45.0 Europe/London",
"customForm": "3",
"displayName": "Salon System Just Wax Vanilla Cream Wax",
"dontshowprice": false,
"enforceminqtyinternally": true,
"excludefromsitemap": false,
"externalId": "0202123",
"froogleproductfeed": false,
"id": "610",
"incomeAccount": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/account/54"
        }
    ],
    "id": "54",
    "refName": "4000 Sales"
},
"internalid": 610,
"isdonationitem": false,
"isDropShipItem": false,
"isgcocompliant": false,
"isInactive": false,
"isonline": false,
"isSpecialOrderItem": false,
"itemId": "0202123",
"itemType": "InvtPart",
"itemVendor": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/itemVendor"
        }
    ]
},
"lastModifiedDate": "2020-04-07T14:43:00Z",
"lastPurchasePrice": 3.27,
"location": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/location/1"
        }
    ],
    "id": "1",
    "refName": "Warehouse"
},
"locations": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/locations"
        }
    ]
},
"manufacturer": "Salon System",
"matchBillToReceipt": false,
"mpn": "0202123",
"nextagproductfeed": false,
"offerSupport": false,
"preferredLocation": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/location/1"
        }
    ],
    "id": "1",
    "refName": "Warehouse"
},
"price": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/price"
        }
    ]
},
"productfeed": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/productfeed"
        }
    ]
},
"seasonalDemand": false,
"shipIndividually": false,
"shoppingproductfeed": false,
"shopzillaproductfeed": false,
"showdefaultdonationamount": false,
"sitecategory": {
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/sitecategory"
        }
    ]
},
"supplyReplenishmentMethod": "REORDER_POINT",
"taxSchedule": {
    "links": [],
    "id": "2",
    "refName": "Standard Rate"
},
"totalValue": 156.96,
"trackLandedCost": true,
"upcCode": "5011522007489",
"useMarginalRates": false,
"weight": 500.0,
"weightUnit": "4",
"yahooproductfeed": false
}
```

The problem is that i am not able to see quantity on hand in any field.
I can see the quantity on hand on the netsuite app on browser for this item.

The main goal is to update quantity on hand for this item.

I have also tried locations like

```
{{REST_SERVICES}}/record/v1/inventoryItem/610/locations/1
```

And the result is

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://3961971-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryitem/610/locations/1"
        }
    ],
    "location": {
        "links": [],
        "id": "1.0",
        "refName": "1"
    },
    "locationId": 1,
    "preferredStockLevel": 0.0,
    "reorderPoint": 6.0
}
```

It  don't shows quantity although this is the locations for which I can see quantity on Web.

This is the result I see on web

[image: Data visible on web for this item]

Comment: You need to use a transaction to change quantity. One such transaction is an inventory adjustment but there are others than can change inventory as well like an inventory transfer that is received.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it from postman?

Comment: Yes you can create an inventory adjustment using suite talk REST calls (POST /inventoryAdjustment).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going to check it out.

Comment: Why did you tag it with `oracle`?

Comment: Because i am using oracle netsuite

Answer (score 3):

As Brian suggested I used a inventory Adjustment transaction to change the inventory Item quantity.

```
{{REST_SERVICES}}/record/v1/inventoryAdjustment
```

I used above POST request to add an inventory adjustment with following body.

```
{
"account": {
    "id": 1325
},
"inventory": {
    "items": [
        {
            "item": {
                "id": {{lastItem}}
            },
            "location": {
                "id": 1
            },
            "adjustQtyBy": 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Note:

- Account is the chart of account i created an expense account naming
  inventoryAdjustment.
- ItemId contains the inventory Item id we need to change.
- The location is the location we specify to which we need the quantity
  to change
- Adjust by quantity is the value by which we need to change the
  quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Adeel's answer helped me get pretty far but I was still encountering problems. I figured it out by entering an adjustment manually in NS and then calling a GET request using the internal id.

```
{{REST_SERVICES}}/record/v1/inventoryAdjustment/{ID}
```

After that I came up with this request which accomplished everything I needed it to.

```
{{REST_SERVICES}}/record/v1/inventoryAdjustment
```

```
{
    "account": {
        "id": "293"
    },
    "subsidiary": {
        "id": "1"
    },
    "inventory": {
        "items": [
            {   
                "unitCost": 3,
                "item": {
                    "id": {{lastItem}}
                },
                "location": {
                    "id": 1
                },
                "adjustQtyBy": 2.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```